# Haskell, make single string from integer set?

Tags: string, haskell, count, int, range

I'd greatly appreciate if you could tell me how to make a single string from a range between two ints. Like [5..10] i would need to get a "5678910". And then I'd have to calculate how many (zeroes, ones ... nines) there are in a string.

For example: if i have a range from [1..10] i'd need to print out

1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

For now i only have a function to search for a element in string.

```
`countOfElem elem list = length $ filter (\x -> x == elem) list`
```

But the part how to construct such a string is bugging me out, or maybe there is an easier way? Thank you.

I tried something like this, but it wouldn't work. 
`let intList = map (read::Int->String) [15..22]`

Comment: maybe you can use [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) and `show` somehow ... (you idea was/is not far of - only that `read` is the other way around - better use `show` and `map` alone will not make you happy - but good start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried something like this, but it wouldn't work. `let intList = map (read::Int->String) [15..22]`

Well... the purpose of `read` is to parse strings to read-able values. Hence it has a type signature `String -> a`, which obviously doesn't unify with `Int -> String`. What you want here is the *inverse*<sup>1</sup> of `read`, it's called `show`.

Indeed `map show [15..22]` gives almost the result you asked for – the numbers as decimal-encoded strings – but still each number as a seperate list element, i.e. type `[String]` while you want only `String`. Well, how about [asking Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[String]+-%3E+String)? It gives the function you need as the fifth hit: `concat`.

If you want to get fancy you can then combine the `map` and `concat` stages: both the `concatMap` function and the `>>=` operator do that. The most compact way to achieve the result: `[15..22]>>=show`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>`show` is only the *right inverse* of `read`, to be precise.</sub>